# When I restart application, a new service runs

Tags: android

I created a service class in my application to run some task in the background. When I close the application the service still running and it's ok. But the problem is, When I run the application again, a new service running and every time when I restart the application a new service create. Here's my code

```
public class myService extends Service {

Socket socket;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    connectSocket();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    socket.disconnect();
}


private void connectSocket() {
    try {

        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.52:2500");
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnected);
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectionError);
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectionTimout);
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        socket.on("test_callback", eventCallback );
        socket.connect();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Socket Connection Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Emitter.Listener onConnected = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.d("SocketIO","onConnected");
        socket.connect();
    }
};

private Emitter.Listener onConnectionError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.d("SocketIO","onConnectionError");
            socket.connect();
    }
};


private Emitter.Listener onConnectionTimout = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.d("SocketIO","onConnectionTimout");
            socket.connect();
    }
};


private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.d("SocketIO","onDisconnect");
            socket.disconnect();
    }
};


int notno = 0;
private Emitter.Listener eventCallback = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
        String message;
        try {
            message = data.getString("message").toString();
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(myService.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.head)
                            .setContentTitle("Message")
                            .setContentText(message);
            NotificationManager nfm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nfm.notify(notno ,mBuilder.build());
            notno++;

        } catch (JSONException ignored) {

        }
    }
};
```

}

and in onCreate method in main class run this code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myService.class));

}
```

Comment: Did you try to start your service from your Application onCreate?

Comment: Yes, I do. what should I done? In the first activity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Every time startService is called, onStartCommand will be called.  This allows it to be started wth different intents.  However it will only be created once (unless stopped for resources, of course).  If you want to only have a single instance of a socket or thread, its your job to make sure you only instantiate them the first time onStartCommand is called.

Also, your code as is won't work.  Services do not have their own threads or processes by default.  That mean you need to launch a new Thread to do your socket work, or you'll get a NetworkOnMainThreadErrror.

Comment: Well I'm a novice developer and I have noooo idea what are you talking about :D, So pleaaaase show me some example and a solution.